# Dimensional axis when using read_file in dicom package in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dicom, pydicom

I have a stack of DICOM images that I'm reading in with the Python dicom package:

```
my_dicom = dicom.read_file('my_dicom.dcm')  
my_dicom = my_dicom.pixel_array
```

My image is a actually a stack of 256 images, each with 3 channels and with dimensions of 256 height, and 256 width.

So I try:

```
my_dicom.shape
```

and get

> (3, 256, 256, 256)

What is the order of the entries in the dimension output? I have a 1 in 6 change of picking the correct hypothesis. The documentation is not illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an Enhanced MR Color Image IOD, you should be looking at (color plane, rows, columns, slices).

In terms of reconstruction of the image, you'll need to look at the photometic interpretation, planar configuration, among other DICOM attributes.

See the IOD for more information on that:

- https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/enhanced-mr-color-image (useful browser)
- http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#sect_A.36.4 (full DICOM standard)

Comment: That's strange, because I have a stack of dicoms that I know are 3 channels, 180 images in the stack, and has a height of 480 pixels and a width of 680 pixels. 
Then, `.shape` gives me  `(3, 180, 480, 640)`